# Correlation among two variables one of which is measured using likert scale

Tags: correlation, factor-analysis, likert

I am doing a study on job performance and demographic variable like age. I have recorded age of 300 employees of a firm. And to measure performance I devised 10 questions with responses ranging from strongly disagree to strongly agree. I ran an exploratory factor analysis and arrived at 3 latent factors. Now I need to run a relationship analysis. And got no idea on how to do it..
Any suggestions are appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried structural equation modeling? It allows you to regress the latent factors on the independent variables, like age, for example.

Comment: Thank you. But, if I had to continue from the output of EFA, then how should I do it?

Comment: I am not an expert on it, but as you already have done EFA, I would do CFA with SEM (structural equation modeling). There are plenty of material in books and internet about doing CFA with SEM.